# Клик по текущей ссылке в vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

У меня есть статический роут, без параметров и чего либо еще. Выглядит, примерно, так:

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: IndexPage },
    ...
];
```

И есть ссылка

`<router-link to="/">Сводка</router-link>`

Каким образом я могу в компоненте узнать, что был совершен клик по этой ссылке или полностью обновить компонент?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. А есть какая-то другая ссылка?  Уточните вопрос

Comment: @Дмытрык вопрос в том, как обновить компонент (или уведомить его о клике по ссылке), когда пользователь кликает на ссылку, на которой находится. Если пользователь находится по адресу `/`, и кликает по ссылке, которая ведет на `/`, то не происходит абсолютно ничего, как будто клика и не было. Мне же в таком случае нужно обновить данные в компоненте (либо вовсе обновить весь компонент).

Comment: А если попробовать добавить наблюдателя `watch: {'$route' (to, from)` в компонент?

Comment: @РустамГимранов пробовал, ничего не происходит (ну, вернее метод не вызывается)

Comment: А да действительно, роут то не меняется. А вам нужно компнент обновить в зависимости от того был произведен клик по ссылке или нет. Тогда может повешать `<router-link to="/" @click='refresh'>Сводка</router-link>` на ссылку роута и определить метод `refresh`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов это не очень хороший вариант, т.к. ссылки могут быть в разных компонентах, и каждой ссылке нужно будет это прописывать. К тому же, такая страница (где нужно обновить данные при клике) не одна, их несколько (страница статистики, сводки и т.д.)

Comment: воспользуйтесь навигационным хуком `beforeRouteEnter` - https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: @Дмытрык он не срабатывает. Как и любые другие хуки роуетера.

Comment: Срабатывает. Это хук не роутера, а компонента

Comment: @Дмытрык не срабатывает. Я же проверил.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Я не правильно тестил

Comment: Тогда возможно, подойдёт вариант с созданием (emit) событий? И, если отношения между компонентами отличаются от parent-child задуматься об [общей шине](https://metanit.com/web/vuejs/4.15.php)? Я понимаю, что возможно решение достаточно тяжеловесное для такого случая, но раз предыдущие варианты не подошли... Минусы - если ссылок в приложении множество то нужно будет не забывать эмитить событие, либо использовать специальный компонент для формирования ссылки.

Comment: beforeEach() тоже не срабатывает?

Comment: @AK это слишком геморный вариант. При разрастании проекта его будет сложнее поддерживать.

Comment: @Денис да, beforeEach тоже не работает

Comment: @maxswitcher, тогда как вариант, можно попробовать с каким-нибудь хешем `<router-link to="/?123">Сводка</router-link>`. Если поможет, можно создать свой компонент-обертку над router-link, который сам будет добавлять хеш когда нужно

Comment: @Денис тогда будет некорректно работать кнопка "назад" (будет отправлять на ту же страницу, если несколько раз покликать по ссылке)

Comment: @maxswitcher а добавить watcher с параметром {deep: true} на $route ?

Comment: @Денис это не сработает, роут-то не меняется. Там вообще вызывается abort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, покопавшись в коде роутера я выяснил, что на текущий момент это невозможно, т.к. там вызывается onAbort с аргументом undefined, если клик произошел по той же ссылке. При этом никакие события не вызываются (в том числе и onError).

В итоге я сделал довольно извращенский, но рабочий способ. Я новичок в Vue, потому, вероятно, кто-то сможет сделать лучше. Предложения принимаются.

Код в файле с инициализацией роутера:

```
const defaultPush = router.push;

router.push = function (location, onComplete, onAbort) {
    if (typeof (onAbort) === "undefined") {
        onAbort = function (err) {
            if (typeof (err) === "undefined") {
                if (router.currentRoute && 
                    router.currentRoute.matched && router.currentRoute.matched[0] &&
                    router.currentRoute.matched[0].components && router.currentRoute.matched[0].components.default &&
                    router.currentRoute.matched[0].components.default.onSameUrlNavigation)
                    router.currentRoute.matched[0].components.default.onSameUrlNavigation.call(router.currentRoute.matched[0].instances.default);
            }
        };
    }

    return defaultPush.call(router, location, onComplete, onAbort);
};
```

Код в компоненте:

```
export default {
    created() { this.loadData() },
    onSameUrlNavigation() { this.loadData(); },
}
```